# Can you open a cursor and return it from a cursor defined at the declaration block?

Tags: oracle, cursor

I would like to do something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_cursor RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
        CURSOR theCursor IS
            SELECT 1
            FROM dual;
        myCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;

    BEGIN
        OPEN myCursor for theCursor;
        RETURN myCursor;
END return_cursor;
```

Is there a way to do this?, the reason I want this is because I have some cursor defined at a global scope in a package, and wouldn't like to re-write them for the call of a function.

I know, i could just delete the global cursor and always use the function, but I still want to know if this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: When I wrote this question, SO told me that my question was not good and would probably be closed and as a result, it has only been seen 2 times in the last 20 mins, I really can't see why the question is bad and I would like to get feedback on why did this happen? How can I improve?

Comment: Not only could you delete the cursor and always use the function you could also delete the function and always use the cursor. Why do you need this in a separate function?

Comment: @Ben To be able to use it in my Java web app and use it in other packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a pl/sql cursor and refcursor are not interchangable, so no you cannot do what you want directly like that.

one option would be to use a view instead, i.e.

```
create view theCursor as select 1 from dual;
```

then in your package just select from the view wherever the cursor was used. i.e. instead of

```
for r_row in theCursor
```

write

```
for r_row in (select * from theCursor)
```

and for the refcursor

```
open myCursor for select * from refCursor;
```

that way you don't have to rewrite the view SQL for this one case.